# Trouble with the start of proving set laws e.g. de Morgan

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I'm currently studying how to do proofs with sets, e.g. de Morgan.

My question is about the first line of the proof. So imagine that the proof for the following statement needs to be provided:

$(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$

My trouble is with the first line of the proof which generally is something like.

$x \in (A \cup B)'$

What is exactly the meaning of this statement? Is it a proposition? Doing the actual proof is pretty much straight forward, but the semantics of this notation are not clear to me.

With the help of the people answering, I believe the proof in this case would be:

$\forall x, x \in (A \cup B)'$

$\forall x, x \notin A \cup B$

$\forall x, \lnot(x\in A \cup B)$

$\forall x, \lnot(x\in A \lor x\in B)$

$\forall x, x\notin A \land x\notin B$

$\forall x, x\in A' \land x\in B'$

$\forall x, x\in A'\cap B'$

Comment: In plain English, two sets are equal $\,X=Y\,$ iff they have the same elements i.e. $\,\forall z \; z \in X \iff z \in Y\,$. The proof usually proceeds by proving the two implications, and $\,z \in X\,$ is part of the first such implication $\,\forall z \; z \in X \implies z \in Y\,$.

Comment: This is a proposition; z is bound by a universal quantifier. So there is no confusion on my side about this statement.

Comment: When you write $\,x \in (A\cup B)'\,$ you assume $\,x\,$ to be an arbitrary variable $\,\forall x\,$. Then you proceed to show that $\,x \in (A\cup B)' \implies x \in A' \cap B'\,$, which completes the proof of the direct implication.

Comment: I think this is the missing link. A hidden universal quantifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "typical" proof of $A=B$, with $A,B$ sets, is made of a couple of inclusions:

> $A \subseteq B \text { and } B \subseteq A$.

In order to do this, we use the definition:

> $A \subseteq B \text { iff } \forall x \ (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

How to formally prove it ?

We assume $x \in A$ and by logical "transformations" we derive $x \in B$. Thus, we conclude with: $x \in A \to x \in B$.

Having proved it for $x$ whatever, we are entitled to "generalize" it (by the $\forall$-introduction rule, or the Generalization (meta-)Theorem) to get:

> $\forall x \ (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

The formal machinery is the symbolic translation of the intuitive argument:

> Let $c$ an element whatever of the set $A$. If we can prove that $c$ is also an element of the set $B$, we can conclude with: if $c$ is an element of $A$, then $c$ is an element of $B$.
>
> But $c$ is an object whatever; thus, the above result will holds for every objcet.

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I was looking for; there is a hidden universal quantifier. Now the initial statement makes sense again.

Answer (score 0):

$x\in (A \cup B)^C$ means that $x$ is an element of the set $(A \cup B)^C$. We are taking some element of the set on the left, and trying to show that it is also an element of the set on the right of the equality. This alone will show that $(A \cup B)^C \subseteq A^C \cap B^C$. Then you must take an element from $A^C \cap B^C$ and show that it is also in $(A \cup B)^C$, which completes the proof of equality.

Comment: I guess the statement isn't a proposition.

Comment: @pveentjer It is your initial assumption

Comment: I understand it is the initial assumption. But is some kind of mechanism to introduce a variable which gets is value from a set. Most proofs are based on a chain of propositions, but this isn't a proposition AFAIK.